# Avoid cell reference to be updated in formulas after lookup query update

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am working on an Excel file where I have this situation:

- a Loohup table populated by a powerquery
- a "result" table where I make soper operations with the results of the powequery

My issue is that every time I update the query, the result table bloses all cell references:
Before update:
`=Ricerca!$V$2`
where the cell referred to is one of the query results cell
Afyer query update:
`=Ricerca!#RIF!`

Cell =Ricerca!$V$2 is regularly updated and contains the expected data after the update.
If I got it eight, this happens because powequery eliminates the lookup table and recreates it from scratch, and the formula autoupdate function of excel fails to track it.
Is there a way to disable the formula auto-update function for a specific table/cell?

I googled up this issue but wasn't able to find working answers. Most requests with the same issue were ananswered

Presently a workaround I've found was using INDIRECT() but u was wondering if there isn't a simpler way. as most cells are using IFS()

Answer (score 1):

Return the data from powerquery into a PivotTable report

[image]

Refer to the pivot table report using =GETPIVOTDATA() function

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I think that using INDIRECT() is easier and more linear than makign the pivot and GETPIVOTDATA() ;)

Comment: Okey-dokey. Hope that works well for you